# why parallel has different meaning in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

below is the standard of html

> **2.1.1 Parallelism**
> To run steps in parallel means those steps are to be run, one after another, at the same time as other logic in the standard (e.g., at the same time as the event loop). This standard does not define the precise mechanism by which this is achieved, be it time-sharing cooperative multitasking, fibers, threads, processes, using different hyperthreads, cores, CPUs, machines, etc. By contrast, an operation that is to run immediately must interrupt the currently running task, run itself, and then resume the previously running task.
>
> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/infrastructure.html#in-parallel

so why this parallel is one after another

Comment: The part referring to parallelism is not _"one after another"_, it's the end of that sentence: _"at the same time as other logic in the standard"_

Comment: This quote appears to be about rendering of HTML by the browser. Not clear where JavaScript comes into it (as per your title)

Comment: here too,is js,https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method

Comment: The text describes a series-parallel operation, where several tasks are executed in sequence _alongside_ other operations. Think of a roadway temporarily splitting into two with multiple cars on each branch.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question is a misinterpretation of the spec language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the clearest wording, but that paragraph is talking about two different things:

- A set of tasks that happen one after another
- **That entire set of tasks** happening **in parallel with** the event loop

So when the spec says "run A and B in parallel", it's shorthand for "perform the sequence A followed by B, *in parallel with the event loop*".

---

Following the link to the section on [Dealing with the event loop from other specifications](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#event-loop-for-spec-authors) explains why the terminology is a bit fuzzy:

> This is compounded by how this specification uses concurrency-model-independent terminology, so we say things like "event loop" and "in parallel" instead of using more familiar model-specific terms like "main thread" or "on a background thread".

If the specification assumed that you were using a main thread and zero or more background threads, the first sentence you quote could be reworded as:

> To run steps in parallel means those steps are to be run, one after another, on a background thread, i.e. not on the main thread.

Or even more clearly, "do A and B in parallel" could become "do A and B in a background thread".

---

So, to use [the XMLHttpRequest example](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method) mentioned in comments:

> Run these steps in parallel:
>
> 1. Wait until either req’s done flag is set or this’s timeout is not 0 and this’s timeout milliseconds have passed since these steps started.
> 2. If req’s done flag is unset, then set this’s timed out flag and terminate fetching.

Means, for a multi-threaded web browser:

> Run these steps on a background thread, leaving the main thread free to continue with other processing:
>
> 1. Wait until either req’s done flag is set or this’s timeout is not 0 and this’s timeout milliseconds have passed since these steps started.
> 2. If req’s done flag is unset, then set this’s timed out flag and terminate fetching.

Comment: so can you explain this? https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method

Comment: As I say, each time it says "Run these steps in parallel" replace it with "Run these steps on a background thread", i.e. "in parallel with the main thread which runs the event loop". The *entire set of steps" runs, in sequence, on that background thread; but the background thread itself runs **in parallel** with other things that the browser is doing.

Comment: @WilkinWendy I've added that example, with my interpretation of it, to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the text is saying the same as you already know:

> To run steps in parallel means those steps are to be run, one after another, at the same time as other logic in the standard.

Let's see: I will run steps [A,B,C,D] ***in parallel*** to steps [W,X,Y,Z]. So both groups of steps (let's call them procedures) are run **at the same time**, and actually  each step is run one after another (D after C, C after B and B after A, and the same goes for the other procedure).

---

*Note: when you read a subordinated sentence between commas, this means that you could take that part out of the main sentence, and the sense will remain valid. In this case, reading this:*

> To run steps in parallel means those steps are to be run, one after another, at the same time as other logic in the standard.

*would be the same as reading this:*

> To run steps in parallel means those steps are to be run at the same time as other logic in the standard.

Now maybe makes more sense to you.

Comment: so,you mean that can be omitted, a little hard to understand

Comment: Of course, like "The dog, which is old and single eyed, ate the food" makes sense without the subordinated sentence "The dog ate the food"

Comment: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-send()-method so,can you explain the parallel part in xhr.send?

Comment: most of the times those commas can be replaced with (and has the same role as) parentheses

Comment: Fetch req. Handle the tasks queued on the networking task source per below.

Run these steps in parallel:

Wait until either req’s done flag is set or this’s timeout is not 0 and this’s timeout milliseconds have passed since these steps started.

If req’s done flag is unset, then set this’s timed out flag and terminate fetching.

Comment: i think these two part in one after another ,isn't it

Comment: I think that (just my tought)... What is saying is that you should run these 2 steps in parallel (async) to the main process. Like  `async function thisRunsInParallel() { stepA(); stepB(); }` then `thisRunsInParallel();`

Comment: the word *parallel*  has different meaning,that's my problem